# Convert Time to String in User Time Zone in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I've got a time with value `Wed, 23 Mar 2016 00:07:00 ICT +07:00`, and when calling `to_s`, it returns me `"03/23/2016 12:07 AM"`, but what I need is `"03/23/2016 07:07 AM"`.

Appreciate an answer with explanation.

Comment: is it a `Object::Time` or a `Object::Date::DateTime` variable?

Comment: @DoubleV it's `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object, that's an attributes from ActiveRecord.

Comment: Actually, Rails does everything already, but I parsed bad date time format from client side, my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you ever need a time in a specific format, you should reach for [`strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-strftime). The format string you want is `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p'`, the manual I linked to above explains what all the format specifiers mean. Anything that is time-ish in Ruby or Rails is going to have a `strftime` method that matches `Time#strftime` so it doesn't matter if you have a `Time`, `DateTime`, `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, ...

You also appear to want to convert the time to UTC but there's a method for that too: [`utc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-utc).

Putting those together:

```
t.utc.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
```

You really shouldn't use `to_s` or `inspect` on times for anything other than debugging. You're better off going straight to `strftime` so that you will get exactly the format you're after.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this would work:

`(t + (7*60*60)).to_s` where `t` is an instance of `Time`.

Comment: @Frozenna think this [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) will help you.